# Getting a parking ticket in order to help a parent

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

My mother asks me to help her carry in some stuff into her apartment. I can't find a legal parking spot. Does the mitzvah of kibud av vi'eim require that I double park and take a chance at getting a $75 ticket in order to help her? I'm aware of the basic din that one doesn't have to spend their own money on kibud av but was wondering if this would be different because of a)it is only a safek loss because there's a significant chance that I won't get a ticket b) theoretically I could probably find a spot far away if I would drive around at which point I could run back to my mother's place and help her. It might be a big tircha and difficult it wouldn't be a monetary loss which would mean that I'm choosing to take the monetary loss because of my own convenience and c)maybe having to pay a fine for double parking is not halachically considered as using money for kibud av since it is an indirect expense. It's not like spending your money to buy a bagel for your father who is hungry.

Comment: Sometimes the apartment complex will allow you to park temporarily in a no-parking zone to move in as long as you inform the office about it. Check with the office and see.

Comment: In addition to *kibbud av v'em* being a personal obligation (*chovat haguf*) and not a monetary one, double-parking might be considered prohibited as a violation of *dina d'malchuta dina* and therefore also not allowed even to honor parents.

Comment: @Loewian I agree with you. But, can you provide support that in this case *dina demalchuta* can override *kibud av*? I understood that *dina demalchuta* applies only where there is no conflict whatsoever with Torah law. Otherwise, Torah law has precedence. I may be wrong with that assumption.

Comment: Besides, possibly, what Loewian mentioned, it seems that double parking may cause a safety problem. What if an ambulance had to get down the block and your double parking was blocking its path? As a result, a patient could suffer long-term injury, illness or die, and you would be indirectly responsible for that. That doesn't sound like a situation to follow your parents at all.

Comment: Also remember to CYLOR and not to use Mi Yodeya as a source of *Halakhah LeMa'aseh*; but, rather, like a good friend's opinion.

Comment: +1 I do not see it as an indirect expense, I see it as a direct one , so it would seem if the mother will take the responsibility to pay the ticket it the son has v'shalom gets one then he needs to respect her, but if he will be responsible to pay it, it would seem that he is not obligated to risk his money for her respect